# Distribution failed, failed_to_start_child. RabbitMQ + docker-compose issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have an issue with RabbitMQ and docker-compose.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  rabbitmq3:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    command: rabbitmq-server
    ports:
      - 4369:4369
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
      - 25672:25672
```

Then I do `sudo rabbitmqctl status`,
and I get this error:

```
Distribution failed: {{:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, :net_kernel, {:EXIT, :nodistribution}}}, {:child, :undefined, :net_sup_dynamic, {:erl_distribution, :start_link, [[:"rabbitmqcli-39293-rabbit@localhost", :shortnames, 15000], false, :net_sup_dynamic]}, :permanent, 1000, :supervisor, [:erl_distribution]}}
```

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Try running that command with sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `epmd -names` in the host, it should output

```
$> epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name rabbit at port 25672
```

That error is typical when the Erlang node is unable to reach epmd, which in your case should be started by RabbitMQ inside the docker and exposed through port 4369

**UPDATE**

After looking a little more into this, you definitely need for `rabbitmqctl` to be able to contact the RabbitMQ node, for which you need the port 4369 port open to access RabbitMQ's EPMD.

This issue happens because the `rabbitmqctl` node tries to register itself in RabbitMQ's EPMD too, but that EPMD rejects it because it's not a local node (in RabbitMQ's EPMD's view, the `rabbitmqctl` register comes from the Internet).

To solve this you need `rabbitmqctl` to both be able to register to a local EPMD and reach RabbitMQ's EPMD.

How to do that?

In erlang, [all the nodes must use the same EPMD port](https://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html#environment-variables), so the only way to differentiate both EPMDs is by their IPs:

Let's use 127.0.0.2 in for RabbitMQ's EPMD. You'd need to start RabbitMQ inside docker as `rabbit@127.0.0.2`, but let's use the `rabbit_in_docker` hostname instead for that (the node becomes `rabbit@rabbit_in_docker`):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  rabbitmq3:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    command: rabbitmq-server
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.2:4369:4369"
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
      - 25672:25672
    hostname: rabbit_in_docker
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: cookie
```

to be able to resolve `rabbit_in_docker` to `127.0.0.2`, modify the hosts's `/etc/hosts`:

```sh
 echo "127.0.0.2   rabbit_in_docker" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

if you let `rabbitmqctl` start the local EPMD, it will fail too, because the port 4369 is already in use for `127.0.0.2`, so you need to start it manually:

```sh
epmd -address 127.0.0.1
```

then, you can use `rabbitmqctl` as:

```sh
 sudo rabbitmqctl --node rabbit@rabbit_in_docker status
```

remember to set the `rabbitmqctl`'s cookie too, you'll find it as `$HOME/.erlang.cookie` or `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` if you have RabbitMQ installed in the host (the cookie was set to `cookie` in the docker-compose file).

Instead of this whole process, I think you should consider running the `rabbitmqctl` inside the docker:

```sh
docker-compose exec rabbitmq3 rabbitmqctl status
```

Comment: @josé_m Thank you for your reply José! I get the same output. `epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:`
`name rabbit at port 25672`. Do you know of anything else that could be the issue?

Comment: @Yolof I've updated the solution with a process to be able to run a local rabbitmqctl, but in the end I think it's easier to use docker-compose. Apologies, I really didn't think it'd be that complex

Comment: @josé_m thank you for updating the answer! Really helpful. But I'm get this error when I do `docker-compose up` after `echo "127.0.0.2   rabbit_in_docker" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts`: `ERROR: for rabbitmq3  Cannot start service rabbitmq3: Ports are not available: listen tcp 127.0.0.2:4369: bind: can't assign requested address`

Comment: Got it. I had to do `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2`

Comment: Thanks a lot @josé_m for the help! You are a true internet hero!